# Best way to display multiple setContentView in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm pretty new to Android so I apologize if this question sounds stupid in any way.

I'm trying to create an attendance application with many classes but the 2 main ones will be Student and Courses.

I plan to use tabs to navigate with Student and Courses being the 2 tabs in my TabHost.

The Course page for example will list all of the courses currently in the system with an options menu for Adding a course which will bring up an Add Course screen (within the Course tab but changing the view).

So, to my question...

I plan to set an onclick for the options menu item which will call setContentView to display the add new course layout instead of starting a new Activity showing a new layout.

Does this sound like a sensible way to do this? If not what would be a better approach?

All my course logic will be contained within the Course class and so I want all of my code to be contained within there without having to create a class/activity for a course list, adding a course, viewing a course etc.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: I know that calling setContentView() on an activity twice throws an exception,

Answer (score 1):

> > Does this sound like a sensible way to do this? If not what would be a better approach?

No, it's not a sensible way to do so. You should open the new activity; that's the Android way. Maybe you are trying to imitate the iPhone tabs style which don't open new windows or something.

If you still want to do so, you better use `ActivityGroup` (there are tutorials out there), which IMHO is a pain the ass to use.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly not a sensible way to do stuffs.

You can however use a ViewFlipper by which you can change the screen layouts. This way you can stay in the same class and change your screen design.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice, so it seems that I was taking the wrong approach. So if I have separate classes for Student, Courses etc logic then create activities for each screen I can pass Class objects around between activities without too much problem?